# How to enable webpack Content Security Policy in React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, content-security-policy

Webpack has a feature of adding `nonce` to all scripts it loads.

> To activate the feature set a __webpack_nonce__ variable needs to be included in your entry script.

Entry file in react app geneated by `create react app` by defaulty is `index.js`. So all I need to do is add in **entry file**:

```
 // ...
__webpack_nonce__ = 'c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=';
// ...
```

And last thing is to enable webpack CSP.

> Please note that CSPs are not enabled by default. A corresponding header Content-Security-Policy or meta tag  needs to be sent with the document to instruct the browser to enable the CSP. Here's an example of what a CSP header including a CDN white-listed URL might look like: `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://trusted.cdn.com;`

However, I got error

```
'__webpack_nonce__' is not defined
```

I've tried to declare nonce. Still doesn't work.

> **webpack_nonce** is specified in the entry file and not in the configuration.

So, what I am doing wrong? Maybe docs are missing some key info about that topic? How to enable CSP feature in webpack for React app?

Comment: So you have added the CSP meta tag in your html file?

Comment: check that this is the real entry point and not some file that other entry point (in cra) that consumes it.

Comment: @hazardous yes. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">`

@felixmosh I checked it. 
path is `node_modules-->react-scripts-->config-->webpack.config` 
and there `entry = [..., paths.appIndexJs]`. Paths.js defines `appIndexJs: resolveApp('src/index.js')`

Comment: Tagged this to [Sean Larkin](https://github.com/TheLarkInn) from webpack on Twitter, hope he takes a look.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? Facing the same problem.

Comment: @leepowell nope

Comment: i'm also trying to follow article at https://webpack.js.org/guides/csp and it seems to be missing detailed implementation details, the 'further reading' section content is verbose, and the stackoverflow link shows a different nonce implementation method, which i have tried but doesn't work. `The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''******''. It will be ignored.` and it is also refuses to load webpack's outputted `bundle.js` (which should contain the nonce as this was included in the entry file:  `__webpack_nonce__ = '******')`

Answer (score -7):

If you are using create-react-app then it may be ESLint that is reporting the error.

Try disabling it for the line:

```
__webpack_nonce__ = 'c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM='; // eslint-disable-line no-undef
```